# Apache php_ldap.dll error

Tags: php, windows, apache-http-server, ldap

I have apache with php 5.4 installed on a Windows 7 64bit machine.  When I restart Apache I get the following:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 
'c:/PHP54/ext\\php_ldap.dll' - %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

The file is present but LDAP doesn't work, any idea what I am doing wrong?  php.ini has the following settings

```
[ldap]
; Sets the maximum number of open links or -1 for unlimited.
ldap.max_links = -1

;extension=php_interbase.dll
extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the problem.

- `libeay32.dll`
- `libsasl.dll`
- `ssleay32.dll`

Need to be in `C:/Windows/system`

Comment: I think the real problem here is that you are missing [c:\xampp\php](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55760) in your systems PATH variable, but of course the problem also goes away when you copy the missing DLLs to a folder that is actually inside your PATH.